# Merge a file from master to existing branch

Tags: git

I had to check something for a previous version of a file. File name was SSNDashboard.twb {a Tableau File} . To test it I created a separate branch "SR_ssn_dashboard_market_line" ; switched to the new branch and reverted the file to earlier commit. After checking this I did a git merge master to undo the commit change I did. But even after doing so I see the file did not align with the master.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: `git merge master` will merge the master branch into your new branch.  If you did a commit when you reverted it, the merge strategy is probably deciding to apply that commit after.  Sounds like you probably just want to `git revert` or `git reset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `revert` you created a new commit. Now `SR_ssn_dashboard_market_line` is ahead by one commit against `master`. So merging `master` to `SR_ssn_dashboard_market_line` won't do anything.

If you want to get the original `SSNDashboard.twb` from `master`:

```
git checkout master SSNDashboard.twb
git commit
```

Or, like @lemonhead commented:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

or

```
git revert HEAD
```